# Adobe Reader PDF Form flickers

Tags: forms, pdf

I have a slight annoyance on my hands. I have an interactive online PDF form that multiple users very actively and routinely use. The problem is, anytime a user clicks on any part of the form, the form goes blank and reloads again. It's still usable, in the sense that the options chosen are being displayed on the reload, but it's still very aggravating and time wasting.

I recently saved a copy of the form so I could test out the form locally, and the issue is still persistant, which crosses out the company issued Internet Explorer 8 as being the culprit, which I thought might be the case.

So, anyone else experience this and know how to fix this?

**UPDATE 4/8/2015**

On further tickering, it seems that the dropdown boxes do contain quite a bit of options. This seems to be slowing down the form considerably. What's odd is when testing on an older PC, the issue is non-existant. Further investigations needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the [known bug](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/What-makes-fields-flicker-q34621.aspx) in Adobe Reader if you are using Adobe Reader or Adobe Reader X to view PDF in the browser.

One of suggestions to try the following:

> Go to (in Adobe Reader) Preferences : Forms,
>   Then untick the "Show focus rectangle" checkbox.

You may also want to try [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) that is also capable of working as plugin in IE and other browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the untick, and then I tried to add Javascript to have that unticked on load, neither of which worked. And, as this pdf form is being distributed amongst a plethora of users, and I'm not technically IT, I don't have the means to install the plugin for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Does this form have many fields with calculations, and some of them leading to change display properties (border, background, text, text size etc.)?

Acrobat often does refresh the appearances, which, when it takes longer than just a few milliseconds, leads to a flickering effect.

In order to provide more help, I would have to have a look at the form.

Comment: The form doesn't include any calculations or fields that cause a change in the design. The refresh occurs when simply clicking on a dropdown box, a textfield, or a radio button. The actual form itself seems to work for the most part, but it's a rather persistant annoyance for the users that I'm trying to alleviate.

Comment: Oh! And I'm not too sure if I can show you the form due to it being technically corporate property and all. I mean, I might be able to, but I'd rather play it on the safe side. :P

Comment: I agree with the annoyance factor. If nevertheless you want me to look at the form, feel free to contact me in private; I am used to privacy and NDAs.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly seen in systems without any GPUs or with iGPU. Monitor color profile and iGPU are bottlenecking in this case.

**Solution:**

1. Set threshold transition framerate to 30fps (con: RAM consumption may increase by 2-3 MB per 100 MB PDF file)
2. For no GPU/ iGPU systems use Software based rendering instead of `DirectX` (under Multimedia and 3-D section, Adobe Acrobat).
3. Set Monitor colour profile to `sRGB.icm` or `sRGB.cdmp` or `scRGB.cdmp` or use my colour profile. Restart your PC. You should see noticeable difference now.
4. ***PRIMARY/ONLY SOLUTION*** is to install a dedicated GPU for your PC. This removes the problem completely.

**NOTE:** 1, 2 & 3 are temporary solution.
I have attached my `sRGB.icm` (`.icm` are ICC profile and they are best) colour profiles here: "https://ln4.sync.com/dl/ca43fd730/actxknji-3t3c5krs-ifagdfin-bppsxinh". Open `colorcpl.exe` (Microsoft Colour management profile control) and load the files. You are all set.

**Cause:**

1. Adobe uses dynamic allocation. Microsoft edge/ chrome transfers the whole PDF to RAM but Adobe doesn't. When you jump to a particular section of the PDF what's happening is Adobe is collecting the data from the PDF and transfering it to RAM, now when CPU processes your data the GPU is lagging behind which is causing the flickering. In most cases this is the problem. The problem is not seen in other applications because they transfer the PDF completely to RAM occupying the size of the PDF file. But Adobe has lower RAM consumption for this reason. Don't open 500MB PDF files in Edge or Chrome because your PC will hang and they will crash, instead open with Adobe, Adobe is well optimized for all purposes, lower RAM consumption. So for this you need a decent GPU.
2. Monitor Color profile mismatch with iGPU.
3. Calibration error.
4. GPU rendering problem(old GPU).

[Threshold fps and other settings to change in Adobe Acrobat Reader/Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGzA.png)

[Color Profile Management for monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSboM.png)

**One Recommendation from me:** Don't ditch ADOBE ACROBAT. It is so well optimized. Microsoft Edge looks good in GUI but when you open a 500MB PDF file it will consume 1GB of RAM, I've seen it, I solve past year questions from a PDF which is of 629MB and edge transfers the whole PDF to RAM and takes 1GB or more RAM. But in Adobe, RAM consumption is about 130MB even when I am editing the PDF. Adobe softwares are designed for professional use. So, don't ditch Adobe because of this silly flickering problem. Thanks.